# Animating md5 models

Tags: opengl, animation, graphics, md5, models

I'm trying to do a proper md5 animation in my simple engine written in OpenGL. I've got a walking animation of a creature. When the animation reaches the end, is starts from the beginning (just as it should), however it is in the same place as it was in the beginning (the creature moves back instead of moving forward). Is there any simple solution of this problem. I tried to move it manually by glTranslatef but I just can't catch the right place where the animatiion should start again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your creature probably has some kind of "root" bone that corresponds to creature's position in space. "Root" bone is invisible bone in creature's skeleton that moves along with the creature and is located at the floor. If there's no "root" bone, "pelvis" bone should do.

So, assuming that the last frame of animation has the same pose (but at different the position), grab position  (relative to root of bone hierarchy) of that bone at the last last frame, substract position of the same bone at the first frame, and you'll get animation offset for the next animation loop.

Comment: It worked, but I still have a little problem. There is a frame rendered just for milliseconds before the right position is set. I don't know how to cope with it.

Comment: @PawełJastrzębski: you should search for opensource tools that render md5 animations and meshes - maybe you're missing something. I mean if the model you're using is from actual game, it should contain all the necessary information to make it move correctly within game. However, if you exported it yourself, then maybe it wasn't correctly set up to begin with, and that necessary information is missing.

Comment: I am actually using an open source tool in my code. I downloaded models from another examples and they behave in the same way, although the model that I am using behaves normally in the other example.

Comment: @PawełJastrzębski: Look, I haven't worked with md5 myself, (I worked with several custom formats, x files, etc). The solution I posted should work, if my assumption about md5 is correct. If there's an opensource example that works with same model, then you should tear that example apart and see how they did it, and then compare it with your own code. That's what I would do if I were you.